# Minimize Shell without minimizing other Shells

Tags: swt

I can see that whenever I **minimize** an SWT `Shell`, all other `Shell`s in the `Display` get minimized along, independently of its modal behaviour (which is not what modal bits are about anyway!)

Is it possible to cut this kind of virtual bond that ties all shells with each other?

---

<sub>I am using Eclipse Neon on Linux.</sub>

Comment: Is the `Shell` you are minimizing a child of the other shell that also minimizes?

Comment: I see.. yes, it is a child of the display's active shell. However if I try to create a new parent shell I get an _Unnamed Window_ empty shell in between (I am using a JFace wizard dialog which builds a child shell on its own out of the shell you give to it).